# If I use CMD + C on my iPhone the information is stored even after restart. But not on Notebook. Why?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone

If I want to copy some information on my iPhone and use CMD + C for it I can paste it with CMD + V after restart. After I turn my iPhone off and on again.

For example I have typed in Safari Browser:

> Hello Stackoverflow

I mark this two words and use CMD + C.

I restart my iPhone. Open Safari, use CMD + V and get:

> Hello Stackoverflow

With MacBook Pro the stored information cannot be accessed after restart.

Maybe its some rules, that the information on mobile version of Apple OS is stored und for "normal" OS, that is used on Apple Notebooks and Desktops is deleted after restart?

Comment: Is your iphone on ios10 but mac on an older version than sierra? iPhone might be using universal clipboard, which I believe stores it in icloud. Older Mac wouldn't have this feature.

Comment: @Vitalydotn iPhone has 10.2.1 and MacBook Pro has 10.12.3 OS. Thanks for your response :)